# Javascript enlarge an image outside of flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

What I want to do is to make an image grow when I hover over it. That's simple enough with `:hover` in CSS, but I also want the surrounding content not to be pushed around. I'd also prefer that the image grow from the center rather than the top-left corner. I could presumably spend hours fiddling with CSS and a lot of media queries (positioning of the surrounding elements varies with the window width), resulting in very messy but functional code. However, it would be much better if there were a simple way to do this in Javascript or Jquery. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but wouldn't a JS or JQuery solution end up using CSS to solve the problem in the end?  OTOH, that solution may be complex and a JS/JQuery lib could make your life a lot easier, so I understand the appeal.

Comment: Possibly, but some stuff (like toggle() ) doesn't appear to interfere with the CSS. Anyway, if it makes it work without hours of tedium, I don't really care what it does to the CSS. My main concern at this point is minimizing the time it would take, since it seems like the kind of thing Javascript or JQuery would have a simple solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `transform:scale()` on :hover of element. 
It will not push surrounding content and it should scale from center (depending on positioning of given element).

Comment: Thanks! Someone in IRC just gave me the same answer, so my thanks also to hipsterslapfight. Anyway, this is exactly what I wanted it to do.